# No such file or directory is Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am learning how to use Azure databricks. I uploaded some csv file in a cluster.
But when I am trying to read those files using pandas or spark I am getting the error
`No such file or directory` even though the file is present at that exact location.

Here is my code

```
[Pandas]
df  = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product.csv")
df.head()

[Spark]
spdf = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferschema","true").load("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product.csv")
```

I get the following error

```
AnalysisException: [PATH_NOT_FOUND] Path does not exist: dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product.csv.
```

The file is present here
[image]

How should I enter the path to read the file from my notebook?

EDIT:
The result of command `ls dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product` is
[image]

Comment: The filename in the code and error message do not seem to match.  The code has `/dbfs/...`, but the error message has `dbfs:/...`.  Which is it?

Comment: The error message is for the spark query. Pandas query gives a similar error message.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to read a delta table as a csv file.
[image]

See what's in the folder:

```bash
%sh

ls -lR /dbfs/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product
```

Or look at it's details:

```sql
%sql

DESCRIBE DETAIL aw_product
```

---

Read a Delta table using python:

```
from delta import DeltaTable

df = spark.read.format("delta").load("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product")
df.show()

# convert to pandas dataframe
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
print(pandas_df.to_string())

dt = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, 'dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product')
dt.toDF().show()

# assuming you created an external table in hive catalog.
dt = DeltaTable.forName(spark, 'aw_product')
dt.toDF().show()
```

Using SQL:

```sql
%sql

SELECT * FROM delta.`dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product`

-- assuming you created an external table in hive catalog.
SELECT * FROM aw_product
```

Some useful links:

- https://docs.databricks.com/files/index.html
- https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#read-data&language-python

Comment: Thank you, the spark query works using delta. Is there a way I can directly read the csv as a pandas dataframe? I am currently reading it as a spark dataframe and converting it into pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Tallion22 which csv file? There is no csv file in your post (run `ls -lR ...` command above). Delta tables store the stuff as parquet internally, but you shouldn't be reading any individual file(s). To begin with you won't even know which parquet file to read when there are multiple versions of table. Use one of the official ways to query the table as mentioned above. Updated post to read a pandas DF.

Comment: The file "aw_product" is a CSV file.

Comment: @Tallion22, please post the output of `ls -lR /dbfs/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product` command to the question.

Comment: I have edited the question, please take a look at it.

Comment: so where is the csv file?!

Comment: That's what I am confused about, the csv file is the aw_product itself.

Comment: it's not. `/dbfs/user/hive/warehouse/aw_product` is a folder, not a file.

Comment: But I uploaded a file. Sorry, I am new to Azure so I am little confused